# Autofac: How do I register generic collections?

Tags: autofac

I have a couple of classes that take `IList<IHero>` in the constructor. I would like to register the generic collection `List<IHero>` in Autofac so that whenever Autofac needs to resolve a service that takes `IList<IHero`, it returns a new instance of `List<IHero>`. The code below compiles but I get a ton of error messages at run-time.

`builder.RegisterType<List<IHero>>().As<IList<IHero>>();`

My current workaround is as follows:

`var printer = scope.Reseolve<IPrinter>(new TypedParameter(typeof(IList<IHero>), new List<IHero>();`

`var newEngine = scope.Resolve<IEngine>(new TypedParameter(typeof(IPrinter), printer));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't register collections yourself. [Autofac handles collections for you.](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html)

Comment: Thank you. It took me a while to realize why Autofac didn't handle the collections in my case... If class Hero is explicitly registered as IHero, then Autofac would handle the resolution of IList<IHero> only if the Hero class has an empty constructor, otherwise the resolution chain IList<IHero> --> List<Hero> --> Hero will fail.

On the other hand, if Hero is not explicitly registered as IHero, then Autofac will resolve IList<IHero> even without an empty Hero() constructor.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, but I'm glad it helped. Please mark this as the answer so I can get credit for helping!

Comment: If I have builder.RegisterType<Hero>().As<IHero>(); and no empty constructor for Hero(), then the resolution of IList<IHero> throws an exception, otherwise it works.

Comment: You need to register everything in the dependency chain. If Hero takes an `IPower` then you also have to register that into the container. Troll around in the Autofac docs. Plenty of examples in there that will help you get where you're going.